# Hyper-V Server 2016: Not able to automatically grab IP addresses for VMs on a VLAN that is set up with IP Helpers

Tags: networking, virtualization, hyper-v, dhcp, windows-server-2016

I'm quite new to this whole thing, so my apologies if my understanding of virtual networking is a bit lacking.

I have a Hyper-V Cluster (Server 2016) and I'd like to be able to configure VMs that I set up on this cluster via DHCP. I'm using an external vswitch with these VMs that is set up with a specific VLAN ID. This particular VLAN is set up with a DHCP scope and IP helpers.

The problem is that these VMs are not automatically grabbing IP addresses even after enabling DHCP on them. I can manually assign IP addresses from this subnet and they work just fine, but the VMs won't just 'grab' them. If I don't manually assign an IP address from that range, it will just be assigned APIPA address. Again, the subnet is set up with IP helpers, so in theory I shouldn't need to set up a DHCP server on this VLAN (or at least that's my understanding).

What would you suggest I try next? Or what additional information can I provide?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Get-VM | Get-VMNetworkadapter | ft VMname,NAme,SwitchName,isLegacy -Autosize